# is there a way to set sql dialect as an environment parameter in docker container?

Tags: mysql, docker-compose

The default storage engine in MySQL is **MyISAM**. How to change it to **InnoDB** using environment param in docker.

```
version: '3'
services:
  #service 1: definition of mysql database
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    container_name: mysqldb
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
      MYSQL_USER: tiktok
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
    restart: always
    networks:
      - spring-cloud-network
```

Comment: did you try to mount `/etc/mysql/conf.d`?

Comment: i want to use it through the environment variable itself.

Comment: Not sure if this is possible using a variable. [Environment Variables](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)